# Known population distribution, plus small sample about one individual, how can I estimate true value for individual?

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Say we have a population of people. Each person in the population performs an action every day, with probability X. In other words, on a given day, there is an X percent chance that specific person performs the given action.

Suppose that we know the distribution of X across the population. Ie, we know that 5% of people have an X of 10%, 7% of people have an X of 20%, etc. This distribution is not a normal distribution.

Now, the actual question...
Let’s say we have one specific person, and I have a very small bit of data about that person. Let’s say I only have 3 days of data about him. On all 3 of those days, that person performed the given action. How can I use the known population distribution, and the tiny sample size of information about the specific person, to estimate the value of X for that specific person?

Comment: One way to cast your problem is by "estimating" $X$ for this particular individual, given that it must be one of a (finite?) number of values described by the population distribution.  A suitable approach would then be to compute the "maximum likelihood estimator" for your setup.

Comment: Do you have any link where I can read about this? I read through some articles on Google but the MLEs they talk about all show you how to fit a curve (such as a Gaussian) to some data points. It’s not clear to me how I can use this to solve the question, since in my case I already know the population distribution. I’m also confused because the data points I have are binary Yes/No. How does that fit with the MLEs?

Comment: That sort of application is called *parameter estimation*.  Your Question is different but shares an important philosophical difficulty.  We'd like to be able to make a claim of the form "the chance (probability) that this individual does action $X$ (say) 70% of the time is $Y$" but we lack sufficient information to make that kind of claim.  I will look for some references, but the sister site CrossValidated.SE might be better to find similar Questions.